# how to convert java code with interface to kotlin,

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Hi I am trying to convert this code to Kotlin. but unable to

Ide could not automatically convert it

```
alertDialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Prevent dialog close on back press button
        return keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK;
    }
});
```

Interface

```
interface OnKeyListener {
        /**
         * Called when a key is dispatched to a dialog. This allows listeners to
         * get a chance to respond before the dialog.
         *
         * @param dialog the dialog the key has been dispatched to
         * @param keyCode the code for the physical key that was pressed
         * @param event the KeyEvent object containing full information about
         *              the event
         * @return {@code true} if the listener has consumed the event,
         *         {@code false} otherwise
         */
        boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event);
    }
```

What I tried

```
  dialog.setOnKeyListener(
            DialogInterface.OnKeyListener { dialog, keyCode, event ->

            }
        )
```

Comment: What's the specific conversion issue you're having?

Comment: I think you need to use `object : DialogInterface.OnKeyListener`, what did you try?

Comment: @grrigore comment is the answer

Comment: What you tried should be fine. SAM conversion applies here, so `object:` is unnecessary. What is the error?

Answer (score 2):

[Dialogs - Official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs)

Create a dialog:

```
val alertDialog: AlertDialog? = activity?.let {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
            builder.apply {
                setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                        // User clicked OK button
                    })
                setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                    })
            }
            // Set other dialog properties
            ...

            // Create the AlertDialog
            builder.create()
        }
```

Set keyListener:

```
//this way
alertDialog?.setOnKeyListener(object : DialogInterface.OnKeyListener {
            override fun onKey(dialog: DialogInterface?, keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        })

//or this way

alertDialog?.setOnKeyListener { dialog, keyCode, event -> TODO("Not yet implemented") }
```